# dictionary with multiple entries

Tags: dictionary, joomla, components

I need a dictionary for my website to enter many words at the same time and give me the meaning of all of them. I use joomla,  so if anyone can give me a code  or model that would be great thank you
example

i type 1. dog
       2. cat
       3. tree

and you click enter and i gives the the deffinitions

```
   1.  dog def.
   2.  cat def.
   3.  tree def.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked through the large number of Joomla extensions for this? An extension like "Free Dictionary" should do what you are asking.

http://extensions.joomla.org/search?q=dictionary

You may have to do a little bit of customisation to make it work with multiple words.